# Tweepy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounding_box'

Tags: python, tweepy

I stream Tweets with Tweepy in Python. The code will give me the following error and quit:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounding_box'`

```
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame()
for tweet in tqdm(tweets_copy):
    hashtags = []
    try:
        for hashtag in tweet.entities["hashtags"]:
            hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])
        text = api.get_status(id=tweet.id, tweet_mode='extended').full_text
    except:
        pass
    tweets_df = tweets_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_name': tweet.user.name, 
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,\
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'geo': tweet.geo,
                                               'coordinates': tweet.coordinates,
                                               'place': tweet.place,
                                               'bb_box': tweet.place.bounding_box.coordinates,
                                               'country':tweet.place.country,
                                               'country_code': tweet.place.country_code,
                                               'type': tweet.place.place_type,
                                               'language': tweet.lang,
                                               'user_created': tweet.user.created_at,
                                               'user_followers': tweet.user.followers_count,
                                               'user_friends': tweet.user.friends_count,
                                               'user_favourites': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': tweet.created_at,
                                               'text': text, 
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source,
                                               'is_retweet': tweet.retweeted}, index=[0]))
```

I already know, it is because there are no Tweets with a bounding box and I believe it has to be a try and except function as well. But after several attempts, I cannot figure out how to code it properly. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `place` attribute of Status/[Tweet objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) is nullable. This means that it can be `None`.
You'll want to check that it's not `None` before using it as a Place object and attempting to access its attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For the coding part: I just put [tweet.place.bounding_box.coordinates if tweet.place.bounding_box.coordinates else None] ?

Comment: `tweet.place` itself is `None`. That's why you're getting the error that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bounding_box'`.

Comment: Ok, thanks I get it, so tweet.place is none. So to tell Python to loop over it until it is not Null. I would write : <br/> `def extract_coordinates(row): if row['place']:
        return row['place']['bb_box']
    else:
        return None` <br/>  ?